# Automapper - RecognizePrefixes doesn't work

Tags: c#, automapper

I have need to map PriorityId -> TcTaskPriorityId

```
 Mapper.Configuration.RecognizePrefixes("TcTask");
 Mapper.CreateMap<Task, TpTasksEntity>();

 Task t = new Task{PriorityId = 1};          
 var te = Mapper.Map<Task, TpTasksEntity>(t);
```

It just does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RecognizeDestinationPrefixes` method.

Answer (score 3):

The RecognizePrefixes works for source object prefixes, i.e.:

```
Mapper.Configuration.RecognizePrefixes("TcTask");
Mapper.CreateMap<Task, TpTasksEntity>();

Task t = new Task { TcTaskPriorityId = 1 };
var te = Mapper.Map<Task, TpTasksEntity>(t);
```

For your scenario you could write a custom naming convention:

```
Mapper.Configuration.SourceMemberNameTransformer = s => "TcTask" + s;
Mapper.CreateMap<Task, TpTasksEntity>();

Task t = new Task { PriorityId = 1 };
var te = Mapper.Map<Task, TpTasksEntity>(t);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.RecognizePrefixes("TcTask");
    cfg.CreateMap<Task, TpTasksEntity>();
});
```